# How can I find the total harmonic distortion of a nonlinear signal. Using matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, distortion, nonlinear-functions, matlab-engine

How can I find the total harmonic distortion of a nonlinear signal. For example, Forced Van der pol Oscillator with code as shown below. I have tried the 'thd' function in matlab but I guess I'm missing somethings. 
This is the equation 
   **x''-mu(1-x^2(t))*x'(t)+x(t)=P*cos(w*t)**

```
function vdpo()
t=0:0.001:10
mu=2
x0=-2;
v0=2;
p=10; w=7;
 [t,x]= ode45(@f, t, [x0,v0])
function dxdt=f(t,x)
dxdt1=x(2); dxdt2= mu(1-x(1)^2)*x(1)+p*cos(w*t); 
dxdt=[dxdt1 ;dxdt2];
end
end
```

Comment: Have you checked [thd](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/thd.html?s_tid=doc_ta) yet?

Comment: Yes I'v checked thd and examples given there are for linear equations. But this is a Second order nonlinear equation.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add that equation?  Most of us are `programmers`, with that background maybe we can help.

Comment: Alright, I'll do just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, in which function `f(t,x)` is our ODE equations and we call function `ode45` to use Runge-Kutta methods to solve it.

```
function [x]=vdpo()
  t=0:0.001:10
  mu=2
  x0=-2;
  v0=2;
  p=10; w=7;
  [t,x]= ode45(@f, t, [x0,v0])
  function dxdt=f(t,x)
    dxdt1=-x(2)-x(1)+(x(1)^3)/3; dxdt2=-x(1)+p*cos(w*t); 
    dxdt=[dxdt1 ;dxdt2];
  end
end
```

However, it is actually a math problem rather than a programming problem. The first thing that we have to do is to transform the equations into a more convenient form by defining `y=x'+((x^3)/3-x)*mu`, then we have 2 `First Order Ordinary Differential Equations` so we could call `ode45` to solve it. I looked them through at [here(page2)](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S1111111102404738).

By calling

```
X=vdpo();
x=X(:,1);
thd(x)
```

we could get an answer like:
[image]

p.s. NOT CERTAIN about THD part.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  But how do I apply thd to find the total harmonic distortion?  I understand matlab has a function to find thd but it simply applies to linear form of equation.  E.g  t=0:0.001:10; u=sin(2*pi*t); thd(u) gives the answer in decibel but how do I apply it to 2nd order diffrential equation?

Comment: Emmm, another mathematics problem, working on it. @Samuel

Comment: I looked some materials, and in my viewpoint THD can be calculated when we have an input wave and an output one, but we only have a solution to ODE equation.  Could you tell me what it is? input or output? @Samuel

Comment: It is an input equation. However, I tried to using this line of code after closing function dxdt, thd(x(:,1) and I have an answer in decibel. Note that the values of x(:,1) are the values being plotted against time.  Do let me know what you feel about this.

Comment: Believe it or not, I am doing the same things since we only have that data. But I'm not sure about it. @Samuel

Comment: Exactly, that is the data available.

Comment: Yes I have the same thd graph here. I came across a material suggesting kalman filter for estimating harmonic distortion. I guess that will be considered later. I'll rather stick to what we have now till a better method is gotten. Thanks so much for your time @Jiang. Your contributions have surely helped alot. Do let me know incase you get a bettee way to go about it.

Comment: That's fine, glad that I could help.